# Problem in reading file using `with` operator in python

Tags: python

I have a code which is using with statement to read a file line by line. The below code goes in infinite loop where line:1 is printed everytime. Not sure what mistake I am doing

```
  with open (config_file) as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        print("line is", line)
        while line:
            match = re.search("^QueueDir\s*=\s*(.*)$", line)
            if (match.group(1)):
                return match.group(1)
```

Comment: Use `for line in fp`, not `fp.readline()`.

Comment: you must give mode of operation while executing ```with``` statement

Comment: @Akshat No, the default mode of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is `'r'`, which is fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `fp` is a file handle, use `for` loop for easy access of elements in the loop.

```
with open (config_file) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        match = re.search("^QueueDir\s*=\s*(.*)$", line)
        if (match.group(1)):
            return match.group(1)
```

The code goes to infinite loop because of the while condition, `while line:`, in the case of conditions, any non-zero values are considered as `True`, so as `line` is non-empty, the condition is interpreted as `while True`, so it runs infinitely.

Comment: `lines = fp.readline()` only reads one line. Your `for` loop ends up iterating over its individual characters. You want `for line in fp:` instead, plain and simple. Also, the `print` refers to an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @tripleee `print("line is", line)` came from OP's code, I didn't notice it, my mistake.

Comment: "Your variable is a list" is still not true, but I guess you can fix that too.

Answer (score 0):

add `line = fp.readline()` at the end of your while loop. As `line` does not changes from one loop to the next.

```
  with open (config_file) as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        print("line is", line)
        while line:
            match = re.search("^QueueDir\s*=\s*(.*)$", line)
            if (match.group(1)):
                return match.group(1)
            line = fp.readline()
```